# Set Notation, null set question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

True or False:

> If $A_1=\{\emptyset\}$, then $A_1$ $∈$ the power set of $A$ for all sets $A$.

I'm confident this would be true if $A_1=\emptyset$, but does the question change since $A_1=\{\emptyset\}$?

Comment: Did you mean "$A_1\subset$ the power set"?

Answer (score 2):

The power set of $\emptyset$ is $\{\emptyset\}$. And $\{\emptyset\}\notin\{\emptyset\}$ because the only element of this set is $\emptyset$, which is different from the *non empty* set $\{\emptyset\}$.

However, since $X\subset Y$ implies $P(X)\subset P(Y)$, we can surely say that
$$
\{\emptyset\}=P(\emptyset)\subset P(A)
$$
for every set $A$, since $\emptyset\subset A$.

Answer (score 1):

A1 is *included* in all power sets. The notions of $\subset$ and $\in$ are different. A counterexample is $A_1\notin\mathcal P(\{1\})=\{\emptyset,\{1\}\}$. But it is true that $A_1\subset\mathcal P(\{1\})$.